# I would like to use Interface inheritance in a simple way that is hard to not understand

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, interface, architecture

I have a Entity Framework Db Context that is injected via dependency injection into three parts of a system that all have some different needs via three separate interfaces.

We need to flow information to the Save method in different ways and today we have a single interfaces for each type like this.

```
public interface IIntegrationDbContext
{
    IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes { get; set; }
    IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(Customer customer);
}

public interface IProfessionalDbContext
{
    IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes { get; set; }
    IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(ProfessionalUser user);
}

public interface IPublicDbContext
{
    IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes { get; set; }
    IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(PublicDomain domain);
}
```

This kind of work but it is a bit of a pain when you start to add a bunch of IDbSets and developers that has to remember to add them to all interfaces, like me :)

So I would like to move all IDbSets to a common base Interface as we have done in the implementation where we have an abstract base class that declares all of these IDbSets and configurations for them.

```
public interface ICommonBaseDbContext
{
    IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes { get; set; }
    IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos { get; set; }
}

public interface IPublicDbContext : ICommonBaseDbContext
{
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(PublicDomain domain);
}
```

But one big drawback with this is that all have to know why we have a common base interface called ICommonBaseDbContext and never try to use that so in a perfect world I would like to have an construct like

```
public abstract interface ICommonBaseDbContext
```

to give a hint on what is going on like in a abstract class.

But I have not found any better way to solve this than the solution with three separate interfaces.

Have I missed any simple and good way to solve this?

Comment: wouldn't `IDbContext` or `ICommonDbContext
` be better name? , btw I did not understand your issue, you can document your code to tell others whats going on

Comment: use [XML Documentation Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx)

Comment: I am not following the issue. Make it known! There should never be a reason to lock down an interface. It's there for a reason and you have interfaces that are even implementing it. Why does it matter if someone implements ICommonBaseDbContext? They're going to have to implement the properties anyway if they implement the other interfaces. This question can make sense if talking about actual classes, but I don't see it for interfaces.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary The names are just something I came up with and not from the implementation

Comment: The interfaces look logical to you, because you know what they represent. We don't, and to me they look nonsensical. What do you need a `SaveChangesAsync(SomeModel)` for in every interface? Why are you creating an interface per model? How are people supposed to use these interfaces? It looks like you're trying to implement a repository pattern in an awkward way. Please try to put into words very explicitly what original problem these interfaces are supposed to be solving.

Comment: @TyCobb I would like to give all devs a hint about why to not try to inject this interface and not stop someone to implement it as that would be ok if you only consume things. But if you try to inject it via dependency injection it will fail as there are a lot of different implementations for this interface. So in many ways it may be more connected to DI than inheritance.

Comment: @CodeCaster The reason for flowing models to SaveChangesAsync is that in our models we use the change tracker to add information to entities when they are created and chaged to not have this redundant all over our business code. But We have three ways to interact with this system depending on user, one is a system generated integration and one is a professional user and one is another type if user and we gather user information in different ways depending on system part. It is a multi tenant system to make things more complicated and some users belong to many tentants.

Comment: I'm sorry, that comment clarifies none of my concerns.

Comment: @CodeCaster And yeah it is not a repository pattern in any awkward way I have made, it´s just how things are made in EntityFramework and the reason for using interfaces is to respect the rest of the system where things is done in this way and because it is really easy to get mocks right with interfaces in tools like Moq. We could of course inject the class instead with a similar result.

Comment: I'm sure if you can show one or two example usages of these interfaces it'll become a lot more clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Is it not just:</strike>

**edit:** as the only real variance in the example you show is the parameter type of `SaveChangesAsync`, my first instinct would be to simply make that parameter generic:

```
public interface IIntegrationDbContext<TUser>
{
    IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes { get; set; }
    IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos { get; set; }
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(TUser user);
}
```

Comment: "Is it not just" is not an answer. Explain what your interface does, so the OP and later visitors can learn from it.

Comment: I have been experimenting with this and it is a way forward but I like the descriptive names in the non generic interfaces when I will read the code a few years later. 

But I will give this one more try.

Comment: After some experimentation this is the best solution if I don´t wan´t to have more than one interface so I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the following:

- You want to share the `DbSet` properties but you want to override the `Save` part of the process
- You want the explicit `DbContext`-like interfaces for unit testing and/or dependency injection

This is the *first iteration* of the design I would think (sorry for the amount of code):

```
// Common Interfaces

public interface ICommonDbSets
{
    IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes { get; }
    IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos { get; }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork<TUser>
{
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(TUser user);
}


// Specific interface aggregation

public interface IIntegrationDbContext : ICommonDbSets, IUnitOfWork<Customer>
{
}

public interface IProfessionalDbContext : ICommonDbSets, IUnitOfWork<ProfessionalUser>
{
}

public interface IPublicDbContext : ICommonDbSets, IUnitOfWork<PublicDomain>
{
}

// Base class to enforce contract

public abstract class AbstractDbContext<TUser> : ICommonDbSets, IUnitOfWork<TUser>
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    protected AbstractDbContext(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IDbSet<DataOne> DataOnes
    {
        get { return _dbContext.Set<DataOne>(); }

    }

    public IDbSet<DataTwo> DataTwos
    {
        get { return _dbContext.Set<DataTwo>(); }
    }

    public abstract Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(TUser user);
}

// Specific implementations

public sealed class IntegrationDbContext : AbstractDbContext<Customer>, IIntegrationDbContext
{
    public IntegrationDbContext(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(Customer user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class ProfessionalDbContext : AbstractDbContext<ProfessionalUser>, IProfessionalDbContext
{
    public ProfessionalDbContext(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(ProfessionalUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public sealed class PublicDbContext : AbstractDbContext<PublicDomain>, IPublicDbContext
{
    public PublicDbContext(DbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(PublicDomain user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Notice that this will force you to **implement** whatever you add to `ICommonDbSets` in the abstract base class, and it will also force you to **override** the `SaveChangesAsync` in the concrete DbContext implementation

**EDIT2:** Notice that you do not need to implement `ICommonDbSets` in your concrete classes (`IntegrationDbContext`, `ProfessionalDbContext`, `PublicDbContext`) because they are already implemented in your abstract base class

Comment: This will kind of solve the problem and I have tried it but it in some way it  defeat the basic idea I had about making things easier to understand. The result is that it instead will be harder to understand what things are for. I have a hard time to accept the idea of encapsulating the original DbContext and still gain enough from it.

But it is a nice idea!